# Is it possible to use a 2D-list as border index?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, indexing

My previous code provides me for each entry of a reference list borders of a interesting region with indices of another list.
So for example I have a listA, which should be assigned to values in another listB. For each entry it should be possible to get the indices, so that is valid:

`listA[:]-d/2 <= listB[indices to find] <= listA[:]+d/2`

I solved the problem with a list comprehension and use the python builtin range() method with the border indices as argument to get all required values. So I loop over my border list and produce a list with all inddices. So e.g.:
`borders[0,:] = [1,4]` becomes `indices[0] = [1,2,3]`.

```py
arr = [values[range(borders[i,0], borders[i,1])] for i in range(borders.shape[0])]
```

It works, but it is too slow for large datasets. I located the list comprehension to be the problem. Is there a numpy/pandas/... method which I can use that it is a kind of matrix operation?

The dataset is similar to the following:

```py
    no_points = 10000
    no_groups = 3
    meas_duration = 60
    df_AT = pd.DataFrame(np.transpose([np.sort(np.random.rand(no_points)*meas_duration) for _ in range(no_groups)]), columns = ['AT {}'.format(i+1) for i in range(no_groups)])
    df_TT = pd.DataFrame(np.transpose([np.random.rand(no_points) for _ in range(no_groups)]), columns = ['TT {}'.format(i+1) for i in range(no_groups)])
    df = pd.concat([df_AT, df_TT], axis=1)
    filterCoincidence(df, window=1e-3)
```

\\ **edit**
Unfortunately, I'm still working on it. I will just copy a piece of my code:

```py
        # process coincidence
        borders = [list() for _ in range(len(AT_cols)-1)]
        test = np.empty((AT_df.shape[0],3), dtype=object)
        test[:,0] = np.arange(AT_df.shape[0])
        for i, [AT, TT] in enumerate(zip(AT_cols[np.where(AT_cols != AT_cols[used_ref])], TT_cols[np.where(AT_cols != AT_cols[used_ref])])):
            AT_ix = np.argwhere(AT_cols == AT).flatten()[0]
            neighbors_lower = np.searchsorted(AT_df[AT].values, AT_df[AT_cols[used_ref]]-window, side='left')
            neighbors_upper = np.searchsorted(AT_df[AT].values, AT_df[AT_cols[used_ref]]+window, side='left')

            borders[i] = np.transpose([neighbors_lower, neighbors_upper])
            coinc_ix = np.where(np.diff(borders[i], axis=1).flatten() != 0)[0]

            test[coinc_ix,i+1]=np.asarray([np.arange(borders[i][j][0], borders[i][j][1], dtype=int) for j in coinc_ix])

        test = test[~np.any(pd.isnull(test), axis=1)]
```

So now this part is fast enough for my purpose. With the hint from Drecker and nakor is is still slightly faster. The problem is now I have candidates for my samples, but I still have to do the following task:

- Order the samples regarding the first criterion: Which the most similar? So I have to compare the transit time and the arrival time (the two columns AT und TT). I could do it with `sorted(key=my_fun)`, but this is really time consuming
- Check if all samples are within the time window. This is fulfilled compared with the reference data, but are the measurements from the two non-reference groups also within the time window? I could simplify the problem by using only +- window/2 in the code, but this is a really strong assumption because the reference measurements should always be in the middle of the time window. Therefore I used `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist()` and checked for the distances

Answer (score 1):

Use direct slices:

```
arr = [values[border_pair[0]:border_pair[1]] for border_pair in borders]
```

If `values` is numpy array this could be at least somewhat faster.

However, this is just simple copy of your data and if this is taking too long (i think) there is not so much you can do with it. But if this is really the bottleneck, maybe you do not need copy all these data but you could use then read-only inside the `values` array? It is hard to tell as you do not mention what you do with them in the question.

Comment: Thank you, I already could increase the speed by approximatly 5sec (from 7) with your hint!

To answer the other question: I have three indepent groups and I want to assigne one sample to another. The first column of a group (Arrival time AT) is a time series and so sorted. The first condition for the assignment is that the samples are within a specified distance e.g. 0.001 sec. The second condition is that if multiple samples satisfy the first condition the property of the sample, the transit time TT, is considered. Hereby the most similar candidate is choosen.

Comment: I just edited the main post with an example of the dataset. The values are in a different order of magnitude but I hope it helps a little bit to understand the data structure.

Answer (score 0):

To complement Drecker's comment, I did some tests on my machine, and it's about 10 times as fast on a 10,000x10,000 matrix if `values` is a numpy array:

```
# Generate random data
import numpy as np

N=10000
values = np.random.randint(0,100,[N,N]).astype(int)
borders = []
for _ in range(N):
    inf = np.random.randint(0,99)
    sup = np.random.randint(inf,100)
    borders.append([inf,sup])
borders = np.array(borders)

In [1]: %time arr = [values[range(borders[i,0], borders[i,1])] for i in range(borders.shape[0])]
CPU times: user 7.97 s, sys: 7.27 s, total: 15.2 s
Wall time: 17.5 s

In [2]: %time arr=[values[borders[i,0]: borders[i,1]] for i in range(borders.shape[0])]
CPU times: user 30.7 ms, sys: 1.4 s, total: 1.43 s
Wall time: 1.43 s
```